# Advantages of knowing for a client, how big the package sended by the server is

Tags: c++, qt, networking, network-programming

I'm really new at network-programming, so I hope this isn't a complete Newbie-question.
I read a tutorial at the Qt-Homepage how to build a little server, and I found [this](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/network-fortuneserver.html):

```
QByteArray block;
QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out << (quint16)0;
out << "..."; // just some text
out.device()->seek(0);
out << (quint16)(block.size() - sizeof(quint16));
```

> At the start of our QByteArray, we reserve space for a 16 bit integer that will contain the total size of the data block we are sending. [We continue by streaming in a random fortune.] Then we seek back to the beginning of the QByteArray, and overwrite the reserved 16 bit integer value with the total size of the array. **By doing this, we provide a way for clients to verify how much data they can expect before reading the whole packet.**

So I want to know, what are the advantages of this procedure? What can happen if you don't do that? Maybe you also could add a little example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is standard stuff.

To the receiving program everything coming over the network is just a stream of bytes.  The stream has no meaning beyond what the application imposes upon it, exactly the same way a file has no meaning beyond how its records, lines, etc., are defined by the application(s).
The only way the client and server can make sense of the stream is to establish a convention, or protocol, that they agree upon.

So some common ways to accomplish this are by:

- have a delimiter that designates the end of a message (e.g. a carriage return)
- pass a length field, as in your example, which tells the receiver how much data comprises the next message.
- just establish a fixed convention (e.g. *every* message will be 20 bytes or type 'A' records will be one defined format, type 'B' records another...)
- just treat it like a stream by having no convention at all (e.g. take whatever comes over the network and put it in a file w/o paying any attention to what it is)

One advantage of the length byte method is that the receiver knows *exactly* how much data to expect.  With some added sanity checks this can help eliminate things like buffer overflows and such in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the packet size before receiving it has a performance advantage.
You can then allocated exactly the needed number of bytes from the heap or whatever buffer management you use and receive all by few (ideally one) calls to the 'network receive function'.
If you don't know the size in advantage, you have to call the 'network receive function' for very small portion of the message.

Since the 'network receive function' (which may be recv() or whatever Qt offers to you) is a system call which also does TCP buffer handling and so on it should be assumed as being slow with a large per-call overhead. So you should call it as few as possible.